# ctypes: How do I define an array of a structure as a field of another structure?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, ctypes

I have a C structure that looks like the following:

```c
typedef struct _DXYZ {
    DXYZSTATE State[];
} DXYZ, *PDXYZ
```

Essentially, an array of `DXYZSTATE`, of unknown size.

When I try to declare this structure in `ctypes`, I'm not sure what to do.

```
class DXYZ(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('State', ???)
    ]
```

What do I use to represent an unknown sized array of a structure?

If it helps, the example for its use in C is the following, malloc'd with a size provided elsewhere.

```c
CurrentState = (PDXYZ) malloc(statesize);
err = update(CurrentState);
```

The update proc fills in the pre-allocated space with the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way but it isn't pretty.  `ctypes` doesn't do variable arrays in a structure so to access the variable data requires some casting.

**test.c** Implements a test function returning the variable structure data.  In this case I hard-coded a return array of size 4 but it could be any size.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct STATE {
    int a;
    int b;
} STATE;

typedef struct DXYZ {
    int count;
    STATE state[];
} DXYZ, *PDXYZ;

__declspec(dllexport) PDXYZ get(void)
{
    PDXYZ pDxyz = malloc(sizeof(DXYZ) + sizeof(STATE) * 4);
    pDxyz->count = 4;
    pDxyz->state[0].a = 1;
    pDxyz->state[0].b = 2;
    pDxyz->state[1].a = 3;
    pDxyz->state[1].b = 4;
    pDxyz->state[2].a = 5;
    pDxyz->state[2].b = 6;
    pDxyz->state[3].a = 7;
    pDxyz->state[3].b = 8;
    return pDxyz;
}

__declspec(dllexport) void myfree(PDXYZ pDxyz)
{
    free(pDxyz);
}
```

**test.py**

```
from ctypes import *
import struct

class State(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('a',c_int),
                ('b',c_int)]

class DXYZ(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('count',c_int),      # Number of state objects
                ('state',State * 0)]  # Zero-sized array

# Set the correct arguments and return type for the DLL functions.
dll = CDLL('test')
dll.get.argtypes = None
dll.get.restype = POINTER(DXYZ)
dll.myfree.argtypes = POINTER(DXYZ),
dll.myfree.restype = None

pd = dll.get()    # Get the returned pointer
d = pd.contents   # Dereference it.

print('count =',d.count)
# Cast a pointer to the zero-sized array to the correct size and dereference it.
s = cast(byref(d.state),POINTER(State * d.count)).contents

for c in s:
    print(c.a,c.b)

dll.myfree(pd)
```

Output:

```
count = 4
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely, but it sounds like this only works if I can set how the data is created. In my case I'm not in control of the data; it's returned from an third-party API. Does that mean I can't use ctypes?

Comment: @user1219358 I built the byte buffer to simulate what you'd get back from an API. I'll update the example with an actual C API when I get a chance.

Comment: @user1219358 Updated example with a test DLL.

Comment: Thank you for all of the work you put into this answer! I got confused by the added "count" field, but I understand what you're doing now, along with using another answer from yours on SO. I'm still having issues with my code, but it's independent of this question, so I'm marking as accepted.

Comment: @user1219358 No problem.  Yes, I added `count` because the C API needed some way to indicate how many `State` objects were returned.